# Installing python library for mesos version 0.28

Tags: mesos

I'm not able to install the python library for mesos 0.28 (Latest as of 2016/3/31)

For previous versions I know you could just install the egg file with easy_install, however I'm not able to find such an egg file for mesos 0.28

Previously I recall there was a link to the egg files for each version in the [Download page](http://open.mesosphere.com/downloads/mesos/#apache-mesos-0.28.0), however now it is nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 1):

The download links to pythong eggs have been removed from the site but you can still get them from PyPI : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mesos.interface

Hope that helps.

[EDIT] 
Forgot to mention that `mesos.native` is packaged with the `mesos` packages you get from mesosphere repo.

Comment: This is only the "mesos.interface" library, In order to implement a Mesos framework you need also "mesos.native" which I could not find on PyPI

Comment: `mesos.native` is packaged into the `mesos` packages you get from Mesosphere repo

Comment: @surdy, do you know where to find the mesos package for mac os?

Answer (score 1):

Only `mesos.interface` can be installed via pypi, but I was able to find various python eggs with mesos.native at the following locations:

http://downloads.mesosphere.io/master/ubuntu/14.04/mesos-0.26.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
http://downloads.mesosphere.io/master/centos/7/mesos-0.22.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
http://downloads.mesosphere.io/master/ubuntu/12.04/mesos_0.16.0-rc2_amd64.egg

Give one of those a shot, or tinker with one of them to get the version/platform you need. That's what I'm doing until I hear back from mesosphere support.